# Airflow - queue up (subset of) new tasks

Tags: airflow

I added 5 new tasks into the dag. I would like to queue up (backfill for historical runs) only 3 of them. I know I can click “queue up new tasks” in the Airflow UI on the particular dag run but that will run ALL new tasks. Is it possible to queue only selected tasks? I tried to look into CLI but did not find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running a `airflow tasks render` command followed by a `airflow tasks clear` command.